# how to replace all non php script by adding "echo"

Tags: encoding, preg-replace

I want to replace all non php script by adding "echo".
Using regex and replacement can be multiline.

example:

`<h1> heading 1 </h1>` ==> `echo '<h1> heading 1 </h1>';`

`<script> ..... </script>` ==> `echo '<script> ..... </script>';`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have removed thanks, you do that by voting on the correct answer.  Please edit your post and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$str="<h1>Hello world</h1>";
echo preg_replace("/(.+)/i","echo '$1'",$str);
?>
```

(.+) is a capture group it captures the entire string and saves it for reuse in replacement perameter as $1.

Live Demo :

https://eval.in/498724